# Using the 4x4 Matrix3D from flash10 for non-affine 2D transforms

Tags: flash, geometry, matrix, flash-cs4, transform

I've been having a very tiresome time when using flash10's Matrix3D class for 2D non-affine transformations. Basically, I have a square in a sprite and four points that form a quadrilateral, and I want to apply a transformation to the sprite to make those points the vertices of the sprite.

There wouldn't be much problem solving this Math problem using 3x3 matrices, like in [this case](http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2007/08/250638.html). The problem is that flash's native transform Matrix class doesn't perform non-affine transformations - which means, there is no way to access the u v w fields of the Matrix class.

With flash10's native support to 3D, it was introduced the Matrix3D class, which allows non-affine transformation, but is a mess to work with. Basically whatever you apply on this matrix isn't exactly what will appear on screen, since it will apply a mandatory projection matrix from PerspectiveProjection class. There is no way to disable this projection, and this perspectiveProjection matrix is always a non-inversible matrix(*1). The method described here - at stackoverflow, about flash10 orthographic projection -, of defining the fieldOfView property to near 0, or the focalLengh to a huge number, won't help to nullify the perspective projection for the edge cases that work with non-affine 2d transformations. This means that even though we can make a projection almost-orthographic when working with normal shear/scale/rotation of a Matrix3D, the same PerspectiveProjection on a Matrix3D with non-affine 2d transforms will still have a undesired perspective projection. Would there be any way to nullify this perspectiveProjection? Or maybe a better way to do it? For now I am using a workaround of separating the plane into two triangles, and applying two affine transforms on them.

Thank you very very much!
Cauê

(*1) when the focal length equals to 1, the perspective projection matrix has the following form:

```
--          --
| 1  0  0  0 |
| 0  1  0  0 |
| 0  0  1  0 |
| 0  0  1  0 |
--          --
           ^ No, sadly this wasn't a typo!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you go and ask [Senocular](http://www.senocular.com/).

Comment: well, it's not what I was looking at the time, but at least there was an answer ; ) Thanks